# Netty do-nothing codec for IO?

Tags: java, io, netty

I'm writing http-server which is going to perform some very heavy computations. I have some encoder-decoder pipeline related to business logic and blocking IO.

```
public void initChannel(Channel ch) { 
    ch.pipeline()
         //All actions in these handlers are very heavy and involve some IO
        .addLast(logicGroup, new HttpRequestDecoder())
        .addLast(logicGroup, new HttpObjectAggregator(Int.MaxValue))
        .addLast(logicGroup, new HttpResponseEncoder())
        .addLast(logicGroup, new ChunkedWriteHandler())
        .addLast(logicGroup, new ResponseBodyDecoder())
        .addLast(logicGroup, new MyBusinessLogic())
}
```

So I decided to create another worker

```
EventLoopGroup ioGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(4)
```

And add simple handler in the very beginning:

```
.addLast(ioGroup, new ChannelDuplexHandler()) //<---- Only for IO
.addLast(logicGroup, new HttpRequestDecoder())
.addLast(logicGroup, new HttpObjectAggregator(Int.MaxValue))
.addLast(logicGroup, new HttpResponseEncoder())
.addLast(logicGroup, new ChunkedWriteHandler())
.addLast(logicGroup, new ResponseBodyDecoder())
.addLast(logicGroup, new MyBusinessLogic())
```

Is it commmon to do like this in Netty? Or there is a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would just not specify the executorGroup when adding a handler to the pipeline if you want to run it on the IO thread. My suggestion would be to structure the pipeline this:

```
EventExecutorGroup executorGroup = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(numberOfThreads);

...

public void initChannel(Channel ch) { 
    ch.pipeline()
      .addLast(new HttpRequestDecoder())
      .addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(Int.MaxValue))
      .addLast(new HttpResponseEncoder())
      .addLast(new ChunkedWriteHandler())
      .addLast(new ResponseBodyDecoder())
      .addLast(executorGroup, new MyBusinessLogic());
}
```

This will have your `MyBusinessLogic` run in another thread and not block the IO thread. If you the `ResponseBodyDecoder` is also very heavy on the cpu / or block you can also use the `executorGroup` here.

Comment: The thing that I just realized is this. Retreiving chunks also takes signficant amount of time. So I would all separate it from IO threads.

Comment: I mean `HttpResponseEncoder` from `ChunkedInput` to the actual response takes lot's of time. `ChunkedInput::readChunk` is kind of heavy operation in my case.

Comment: Then move it off the EvenLoop as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am still a little bit confused. The question is what are I/O threads then?